# std::string::empty() const () segfault without throwing

Tags: c++, c++11, stdstring

I've run into a peculiar issue I can't figure out atm:

```
  for ( const auto & p : _patterns )
  {
     auto it = std::find_if( p->Tokens().begin(),p->Tokens().end(),
                             [&]( const Token & lhs )
                             {
                               return ( lhs == query );
                             });

    if ( it != p->Tokens().end() )
      d_freq++;
  }
```

Tokens is:

```
std::vector<Token>
```

and the actual operator from inside the std::find_if lambda, is defined and implemented as:

```
bool Token::operator== ( const Token & rhs  ) const
{
  if ( !this->_value.empty() && !rhs._value.empty() )
  {
    return boost::iequals( this->_value, rhs._value );
  }
  else
    throw 
      std::runtime_error ( "[Token::operator==] empty string" );
}
```

Running my debug version simply crashes with a SEGFAULT.

Only when I run gdb, and then backtrace, I get:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff721b173 in std::string::empty() const () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
(gdb) backtrace 
#0  0x00007ffff721b173 in std::string::empty() const () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x00000000005b082d in Token::operator== (this=0xc35818, rhs=...) at /Token/Token.cpp:37
#2  0x00000000005ee12a in TFIDF::Calculate(std::vector<Token, std::allocator<Token> >, Token)::{lambda(Token const&)#1}::operator()(Token const&) const (__closure=0x7fffffffd840, lhs=...)
```

I find this very bizarre, because, if I understand correctly, it should throw a nice exception, but it doesn't.

Even more interestingly, right before I call the method from which it crashes (TFIDF::Calculate) I do a very similar search using the same token, the same std::find_if, and the exact same lambda, and it doesn't crash!

I'm obviously missing something, so could somebody please help?

Comment: I know that feeling bro ...

Comment: It segfaulted. That does not require a nice exception in any way. You likely have undefined behaviour somewhere else.

Comment: @chris so the backtrace is giving me the wrong line, I should be looking elsewhere?

Comment: @Alex, I have no idea whether it's onto something or not. That's undefined behaviour or you. It could be some array you ran past the end of messing with the string and causing it to segfault when you call `empty` for all I know.

Comment: Can you boil this down into a [short, self-contained, correct, compileable example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @AdamRosenfield I'm afraid not, its nested code within many classes.

Comment: @Alex Is `Tokens()` returning the `std::vector<Token>` by value?

Comment: @Alex Your code is within a class called `Token`.  That class requires an instance.  That instance of the class could be invalid, but you're using that invalid instance.  Therefore the most innocuous looking code can cause an issue if that `Token` instance isn't valid.  For example `Token& foo() { Token t; ... return t; }` and then your calling code uses the return value.  That is just one way things like this can happen.

Comment: Valgrind didn't produce anything useful. @Praetorian yes its by value, not reference.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie that's what I'm starting to think, it might be an invalidated iterator somewhere, ty for pointing that out

Comment: Help the slow guy (me). `Tokens()` doesn't return a ***reference***?  That's *bad*. Once you fix that, you need not inquire this with a lambda either. [`std::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) should do what you want if all you seek is locating a match.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm going to steal that second part :)

Comment: @Praetorian pilfer away!.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [stated in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319329/stdstringempty-const-segfault-without-throwing/24319465#comment37589556_24319329), `Tokens()` returns a `std::vector<Token>` *by value*. This means that the following code is going to compare `begin` and `end` iterators of two different `vector`s, which is undefined behavior.

```
auto it = std::find_if( p->Tokens().begin(),p->Tokens().end(),
                        [&]( const Token & lhs )
                        {
                          return ( lhs == query );
                        });
```

---

To fix the problem, either modify `Tokens()` so that it returns the `std::vector` *by reference*, or store the return value in a variable.

```
auto tokens = p->Tokens();
auto it = std::find_if( tokens.begin(), tokens.end(),
                        [&]( const Token & lhs )
                        {
                          return ( lhs == query );
                        });
```

---

And as @WhozCraig [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319329/stdstringempty-const-segfault-without-throwing#comment37589568_24319329), this can be further simplified to

```
auto tokens = p->Tokens();
auto it = std::find(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), query);

if ( it != tokens.end() ) // don't use p->Tokens() here either!! :)
  d_freq++;
```

Comment: Why `p->tokens` instead of just `tokens`?

Comment: Because I'm not paying attention. Thanks

Comment: yes, that fixed it. I've seen it happen before, but I'll admit I did not understand why. Thank you very much, because this has been haunting me quite a few times.